# In Matlab how to get the center CoG and other features of a contour?

Tags: matlab, contour, feature-extraction

I have an image and I am getting the contours with the function `contourc()` which outputs the contours values but not plot. `contourf` always plot (I dont need it and it has computational cost)  What I want is to extract features from this contours like center of gravity, area, and others, features that I could get in a boolean image with `regionprops`. One contour level could have different objects, but just the pixels that belong to same level and are together makes an object.

i.e. I need the matrix I get with `contourf` but wihtout plotting, with that I could threshold the levels and use easily `regionprops`

How could I get those features having the contours?

Comment: you may want to have a look at `regionprops`

Comment: Would values that belong to the same contour level thus belong to the same object?  It's a bit difficult without an actual example.

Comment: @AnderBiguri regionprops does not accept the result of the contourc function

Comment: @rafaoc no it doesnt. But its ridiculusly easy to get something that `regoinprops` accept. E.g. if your contour is on level 0.5, you can do  `regionprops(mydata>0.5,'whatever')`

Comment: @rafaoc Exactly what Ander said.  You could simply loop over all unique values of `contourf`, create a mask and use that as the input into `regionprops`... this is **assuming each contour level belongs to an object**.  If it doesn't, then `regionprops` will give you very interesting output.

Comment: @AnderBiguri in the vector I get with `contourc` I get in some positions the level value, other items refer to the (x,y) pair value of the contour line. So I cant do mydata>0.5

Comment: @rafaoc not in the vector that contourc gives, do it in the data itself

Comment: @AnderBiguri you are right, so it's the way to do that. Thanks